# Fix seeks/repair timestamps in video

Tags: video, editing, encoding, avi

I have a few videos that have bad timestamps. I can't really seek the video. I don't want to re-encode the video, just fix the timestamps. Is there an app to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which video player?

What kind of videos? AVI? WMV?

This might fix WMV files where you cannot seek - http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/mediaadvice/0064.mspx#EKG